# auth helper methods using application_controller or helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create my authentication system from scratch and I'm not really looking for debate in this area. My question is should I be using a helper file to provide methods such as current_user and signed_in? or is it preferred to provide these through the application_controller? or does it not matter in the slightest and I just need to get on with it?

Comment: I think you would need those methods in controller and views, so define them in controller and mark them as helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in the `ApplicationController`, you can define something like

```
def current_user 
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

This will allow you to call @current_user from your views and controllers.